# What method gets called when you display an object?

Tags: python

Assume I have a class that inherits from object. I create an instance of it pass that to print. It will display something like `<__main__.ObjName object at 0xxxxxx>`. Is there an object method that can be overridden to provide a return value when the object is accessed this way?

Comment: if you don't define str then the output is using repr

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) and [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! Any key pitfalls using one of these vs the other?

Comment: @Lother have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Either
     `__repr__`or `__str__` will do it.